# CMake Выполнить команду если изменился файл

Tags: cmake

Прошу помощи. Цель такова: При изменении файла `yes.txt` (его содержимого) нужно запускать команду на запись в файл `docs.txt`. 
  Пожалуйста удержитесь от вариантов использования configure_file, акцентирую внимании на обязательном выполнении какой-либо операции. Ибо вместо обычной команды `echo "HELP" >>` может стоять программа для генерации кода, например `xdrc` .

Есть примерный набросок:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(myproj)

set(OUT_FILES docs.txt)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUT_FILES}
        COMMAND echo "HELP" >> docs.txt
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY yes.txt
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_executable(myproj main.cpp ${OUT_FILES})
```

Такой вариант не работает.

Но если заменить `${OUT_FILES}` на `test` или какое-нибудь другое имя. То все работает, но в файл записывается постоянно, независимо от того изменился ли файл `yes.txt` или нет.

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT test
        COMMAND echo "HELP" >> docs.txt
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY yes.txt
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )

add_executable(myproj main.cpp test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в Вашем скрипте в том, что у Вас неправильно указаны пути. `WORKING_DIRECTORY` команды `add_custom_command` влияет только на `COMMAND` оной (в Вашем случае это рабочая директория, в которой будет выполнена команда `echo`). Но если `yes.txt`у Вас лежит в `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` и туда же должен складываться `docs.txt`, тогда это должно выглядеть так:

```
set(OUT_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/docs.txt)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUT_FILES}
        COMMAND echo "HELP" >> docs.txt
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/yes.txt
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.